# Create a new project with auth flag is not working

Tags: laravel-6

When I'm creating a new project with auth by run `laravel new project-name --auth` it's showing me this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first install the Laravel Installer globally.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Then...

```
laravel new project-name

cd /project-name

composer require laravel/ui

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

For reference, here is the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#installing-laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend

Comment: yah this is right but I'm talking about the documentation says that _If you are starting a brand new application and would like to include the authentication scaffolding, you may use the `--auth` directive when creating your application. This command will create a new application with all of the authentication scaffolding compiled and installed:_  `laravel new blog --auth` this is not working and why

Comment: You need to install the installer first: composer global require laravel/installer

Comment: yah I have, I'm creating projects with this command `laravel new blog` but when I run the above command it gives that error.. btw how to check my laravel installer is installed globally or not.?

Comment: Depends on your platform.

Comment: I'm on windows 10

Comment: Try under %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming. You should see a Composer entry as well: Composer\vendor\bin